# Spring FTP Inbound Channel Adapter log every certain time to the FTP

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration

quick question
So in the FTP inbound channel adapter how to log for example every 10 minutes to the remote FTP, is the poller fixed rate what does this? the poller is for polling but it keeps logged into the remote server?

I have this:

```
@Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {

        FtpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);

        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(remotedirectory);
        messageSource.setFilter(filter());

        return messageSource;
    }
```

or the poller METADATA trigger:

```
 @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
        public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
            PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
            pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
            return pollerMetadata;
        }
```

or how to log every 10 minutes and then poll all new files, setting a Thread.sleep() ?

_______EDIT___

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FtpinboundApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(remotehost);
        sf.setPort(remoteport);
        sf.setUsername(remoteuser);
        sf.setPassword(remotepassword);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "data", adviceChain = "after")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                try {
                    httpposthgfiles.getHGFilesfromRestful(message.getPayload().toString());
                    httppost990.get990fromRestful(message.getPayload().toString());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice after() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setOnSuccessExpression("@template.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'])");
        advice.setPropagateEvaluationFailures(true);
        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {

        FtpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);

        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(remotedirectory);
        messageSource.setFilter(filter());

        return messageSource;
    }

    public FileListFilter<FTPFile> filter() {
        CompositeFileListFilter<FTPFile> filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filter.addFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("xxxx_aaa204*"));
        filter.addFilter(acceptOnceFilter());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter acceptOnceFilter() {
        FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter filter = new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(meta(), "xxxx_aaa204");
        filter.setFlushOnUpdate(true);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMetadataStore meta() {
        PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore meta = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
        meta.setBaseDirectory("/tmp/foo");
        meta.setFileName("ftpStream.properties");
        return meta;
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "stream", outputChannel = "data")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
        return new StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
        return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(ftpSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only stay logged in if you use a `CachingSessionFactory`.

It's better not to sleep and tie up a thread like that, but use the task scheduler (which is what the poller does).

`new PeriodicTrigger(600_000)` will schedule a task to log in and check for files once every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks so much Gary, Look I edited adding my code, I have: return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf)  but also have the @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER) with pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));  Do i have to remove the cachingSessionFactory? or it should log every 5000 miliseconds as i have it now? thanks

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments; it's unreadable; always edit your question and add a comment to indicate you have done so. If you use a caching session factory, the session will remain open between polls (although most servers close idle connections after a timeout). It is not clear what you are asking; with 5000 it will check for files every 5 seconds, with 600_000 it will check every 10 minutes.

Comment: @viruskimera just use the DefaultFtpSessionFactory it should be good enough for usual polling tasks. Set the -1 for the max-messages-per-poll to grab all of files from the ftp

Comment: OK what I meant was if I needed to remove CachingSessionFactory and set 600_000  in my current code (in my EDIT) to log every 10 minutes, according to @SergeyBenner (I think) yes since I would return "sf" in my code (the defaultSession) and my PollerMetadata above would take effect.